# Android audio and video doesn't play on webview from loaded HTML page

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing epub reader for Android devices. Audio and video doesn't play on webview from loaded HTML page. It seems like audio and video tags are not working. I have seen some solution like this:`<video src="soundfile.mp3" onclick="this.play();"></video>`. But how I can change particular (`<audio>`) tag from loaded HTML file.

This is my webview settings:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    webView.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/myfolder/epubfile/OPS/02-audioDemo.xhtml");
```

What I have do for playing audio and video on my weview. Please help me to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

first: use  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() because /mnt/sdcard/ does not work all the time on all android devices.  and also  getExternalStorageState() this checks if the media is even available.

also its probably not this because i blievve at the moment this is not enforced but try adding permission to read SDcard:

check this first and respond back.

Comment: i am using it to get rootpath of my file. that was just fastest way to produce, thats not my complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this extended HTML5 Webview for those type of HTML5 audio and video. https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/